# No me deja ingresar los datos en una estructura de arrays

Tags: c, loops

Disculpen, seguramente es algo sin mucha dificultad para ustedes pero recién estoy empezando en este lenguaje, mi error es algo lógico seguramente que no logro comprender ya que siento que todas las sentencias aritméticas están realizadas correctamente. Tengan en cuenta que al código le faltan algunos aspectos técnicos como los prototipos de las funciones, esto ocurre porque el código todavía no esta finalizado.

El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define elementos 3

struct clientes{
    char nombres[30];
    char apellidos[20];
    char numero[10];
    char edad;
};

struct clientes clientes1[elementos];

int main()
{
    int opc=0;

    do{
        printf("MENU DE OPCIONES\n");
        printf("1- Altas\n");
        printf("2- Bajas\n");
        printf("3- Modificacion\n");
        printf("4- Salir\n");
        scanf("%d", &opc);

        while(opc<1 || opc>5){   //verifico si la opción ingresada esta en el rango
            printf("Por favor ingrese un numero del 1 al 4\n");
            scanf("%d", &opc);
        }

        switch(opc){
            case 1:
                system("cls");
                altas();
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
            break;
        }
    }while(opc!=4);

    return 0;
}

void limpiar(){
    system ("cls");
    printf("la pantalla esta limpia\n");
}

void altas(){
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<elementos; 
    i++) //aca se encuentra el error
    {
        printf("ingrese el nombre del cliente ");fflush(stdout);
        gets(clientes1[i].nombres);
        printf("ingrese el apellido de su cliente "); fflush(stdout);
        gets(clientes1[i].apellidos);
        printf("Ingrese el numero de telefono de su cliente ");fflush(stdout);
        gets(clientes1[i]. numero);

    }

    for(i=0; 
    i<elementos; i++){

        printf("su nombre es %s \n", clientes1[i].nombres);
        printf("su apellido es %s \n", clientes1[i].apellidos);
        printf("su numero de telefono %s \n", clientes1[i].numero);
    }
}
```

La salida me da como respuesta que al ingresar la opción de altas (1) no me deja ingresar el primer nombre sino que se saltea hasta la linea de código para ingresar el apellido, con las demás iteraciones (dos mas en total) no tengo ningún problema solamente ocurre en la primer iteración.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `scanf` para almacenar el dato directamente, pero necesita ser tipo `array`, igual podrías usar `malloc`.

Este es el código con que podrías notar tu error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXIMO_CARACTERES 100

int main() {
    struct clientes {
        char nombres[MAXIMO_CARACTERES];
        char apellidos[MAXIMO_CARACTERES];
        int numero;
        int edad;
    } lista;

    printf("Escribe el nombre: ");
    scanf("%s", &lista.nombres);

    printf("Escribe el los apellidos: ");
    scanf("%s", &lista.apellidos);

    printf("Escribe un numero: ");
    scanf("%i", &lista.numero);

    printf("Escribe tu edad: ");
    scanf("%i", &lista.edad);

    printf("\nTe llamas: %s\nTus apellidos son: %s\nEscribiste el numero: %i\nEdad: %i\n", lista.nombres, lista.apellidos, lista.numero, lista.edad);
}
```

Otra cosa es que si edad es un númerico debe ser tipo entero. Te enseñaré los tipos de datos básicos comparándolo con `Lua`:

```
Lua: i = 1 (entero i = 0)
C: int i = 1 (int(entero) i = 0)

Lua: palabra = "hola"
C: char *palabra = "hola";

Lua: flotante = 1.2
C: float flotante = 1.2;

Lua: function escribir(palabra) print(palabra) end (no retorna nada)
C: void escribir(char *palabra) { puts(palabra); };

Lua: function retornar(palabra) return palabra end (retorna la palabra en la función)
C: char *retornar(char *palabra) { return *palabra; };
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedo responder por mi raputación jaja XD

Pero para comparar el tamaño de una lista se usa sizeof

```
char m[] = {1, 2, 3};
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(m); i++) {
      // código
}
```

Si quieres comparar una cadena del array usa strlen incluyendo string.h en la cabezera

Answer (score 0):

He probado el código en mi móvil y efectivamente me ocurre lo mismo. He hecho una variación para ver dónde está el error, ejecutando la función `altas` directamente. Creo que el error está en la función `fflush` que no funciona adecuadamente. Prueba a poner cuando pides la entrada de la opción lo siguiente:

```
scanf("%d%*c", &opc) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que señalas es un problema conocido de scanf. Lo que se recomienda es
limpiar el buffer con

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
```

El bucle getchar() != '\n' trabaja porque al llamar getchar(), se limpia el input stream.

ver: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c